# Reset auto increment (id) when running test suite?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Lets say I have this test:

```php
class test extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function test_ids_example()
    {
        $courses = factory(Post::class, 3)->create();
        $this->assertEquals([1, 2, 3], $courses->pluck('id')->toArray());
    }

    /** @test */
    public function test_ids_example_2()
    {
        $courses = factory(Post::class, 4)->create();
        $this->assertEquals([1, 2, 3, 4], $courses->pluck('id')->toArray());
    }
}
```

When I run the the test one by one, it passes..
but when I run the whole test file I get this error:

```
test::test_ids_example_2
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
-    0 => 1
-    1 => 2
-    2 => 3
-    3 => 4
+    0 => 4
+    1 => 5
+    2 => 6
+    3 => 7
 )
```

Because the tests doesn't reset the auto increment "id" even though I added "**RefreshDatabase**" trait. How to solve this? How can I rest the id for each test?

Comment: Can you try calling refreshDatabase method manually after each test method.  $this->refreshDatabase()

Comment: @ErkanÖzkök still, the same issue

Comment: What test database software are you using (MySQL, SQLite, ...)? Laravel handles refreshing these differently.

Comment: @AkenRoberts Mysql

Comment: Why are you testing the ids? I'm just thinking there might be a different way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: @RossWilson Well I am trying to test the order of the posts..

When a user enters a URL like localhost/posts/?order=id,desc Or localhost/posts/?order=id,asc .. If you didnt understand this, tell me so I can update my post by adding a more clear test example..

Comment: It's not very elegant to rely on auto incremented ids for ordering data. Have you considered adding an explicit field for it instead?

Comment: @PtrTon Yeah, I have found an alternative way other than "auto incremented ids"

Comment: The same thing has been happening for me with `DatabaseTransactions`, and I see this explanation: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13241#issuecomment-212762904

Comment: I need to check ID's to confirm that a json return is returning the correct id object, so the question I think is relevant...